# ruby on rails equivalent of $_GET from PHP test if set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been searching with not much luck for this... I have the code

```
url = params[:url];
if url == "" 
    @myString = "No URL specified, cannot continue"
else
=begin
    DO SOME STUFFS....
=end
end
```

But the DO SOME STUFFS is still getting called. I have my index page which I perform actions on the _GET variables. I'd like to load the index page without the parameters in the URL. How do I check if they are set - if they're not, then display a message. If they are, process the requests...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = params[:url]
if url
  # do stuff
else
  @my_string = "No URL specified, cannot continue"
end
```

`params[:url]` will be `nil` if not provided.  `nil` evaluates false in a conditional.

Comment: it won't work if url is empty. You should use `if url.blank?` here.

Comment: Using `if url = params[:url]` would remove the awkward line at the top

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
url = params[:url];
if params[:url].nil? 
    @myString = "No URL specified, cannot continue"
else
    DO SOME STUFFS....
end
```

When `params[:url]` is empty it's equal to `nil`, not `""`.

Comment: when params is empty, it's equal nil not ""

Answer (score 1):

use `if url.blank?`
blank? checks for nil and empty string and if you are not passing the url then accessing params[:url] would return nil. That is why your condition is failing.

Answer (score 1):

rails 5:

```
@myString = "No URL specified, cannot continue" unless params[:url]
```

Short and simple